# "Expected ')' to match this '(' "when adding & to function prototype

Tags: c, gcc, struct, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a recursive bst insert function and I recognized that I was modifying a copy of the struct.

So I changed the prototype of the function from this:

```
void BSTRecursiveInsert(BSTNode* tree, DataObject* elem)
```

to this:

```
void BSTRecursiveInsert(BSTNode*& tree, DataObject* elem)
```

but I get the compiler error I wrote as question title. What am I missing?

Comment: `BSTNode*& tree` is not C syntax.

Comment: confused with C++? should I use BSTNode** instead?

Comment: That depends on whether you are hiding a pointer behind a `typedef`.

Comment: It is valid C++ syntax, are you using the correct language?

Comment: "*should I use BSTNode\*\* instead*" this we cannot answer as you miss to show the relevant code. Also its sort of worth another question.

Comment: What is the exact error message, because I doubt that it is "`Expected ')' to match this '(' when adding & to function prototype`" as you have stated.  Some of that text was added by you.  Include the verbatim copy & pasted diagnostic in your question.

Comment: The original function declaration takes  a _pointer_ to a caller's `BSTNode`, not a _copy_.  So it seems that your assumption of what the original error is is incorrect - making this an X-Y question.  Other than that in C, to pass a reference to a pointer you use a pointer to a pointer, i.e. `BSTNode**` ; C does not have reference types like C++ if that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: I didn't know it wasn't C syntax. Changing the return type of the function from void to BSTNode* and modifying some lines solved the problem.

Answer (score -4):

& is for reference and 
* is for  pointer

```
#include <iostream>
main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *y = &x;
    int &z = x;
    std::cout << x << "," << *y << "," << z << std::endl;
}
```

Once you understand this, you'll understand the mistake you made.

Comment: That answer is for C++ (although I think you are using the wrong `&`) the question is quite clearly tagged C and `gcc`, not C++ and `g++`.